# I have this custom post type but cant figure out how to view it on my site

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

Here is my custom post type in functions.php. what I'm trying to accomplish is: Make tab translations and a pull title to a template in a child theme. But not through for example: translation-test.php, rather

(and not thru acf)

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $label = 'Translations';
    $type = 'translation';
    register_post_type( $type, [ 'public' => true, 'label'  => $label ] );
});
```

cant find a simple explanations, everybody writes for slugs, sub-cats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to register the post type like this way into your function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'reg_post_your_fn' );

function reg_post_your_fn() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

In above code "book" is a post type.

Now if you open wordpress admin then you will see that the Book post type is created in left menu. Now add some posts into it.

Then you have to make a template or in index.php you can add this below code to show the posts.

```
    $args = array('post_type' => 'book');

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
echo "No post found."
     }
```

Comment: is it possible to simplify it for just title?

Comment: you can use get_the_title($post_id) for it.

Answer (score 0):

To show post on the front end you have to place code on template page like this :

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'public', 'paged' => $paged ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="entry">
<h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<!-- show pagination here -->
<?php else : ?>
<!-- Show some message here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: isent it possible to example do a if post_type is translation echo the_title? or like this

Comment: or like this 
    $obj = get_post_type_object( 'your_post_type_name' ); 
    echo esc_html( $obj->description );